# Positioning 2 div side by side in a squared container embed in an iframe

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a CSS problem when I want to position 2 divs side by side in a container embed in a squared iframe.

## The problem

- The iframe has a fixed height and width and is a square. However, its dimensions are generated in javascript so I don't know them in advance.
- The container has a `width:100%; height: 100%;`.
- The first div has a variable width: it contains a dynamically selected image with a `height: 100%;` and the ratio height/width of this image is variable (but is never < 1).
- I want the second div to take the remaining width of the container.

I'm working on the CSS of the container and its subelements.

My problem is that I can't make the second div take all the remaining space.

## The situation

```
.==iframe==================.
|.======container=========.|
||                 |      ||
||                 |      ||
||      1st div    | 2nd  ||
||                 | div  ||
||                 |      ||
||                 |      ||
||                 |      ||
||                 |      ||
||                 |      ||
|.========================.|
.==========================.
(please, imagine that iframe and container are squared :))
```

## My results

After reading lots of answers on StackOverflow, I understood that I have to add `display: inline-block;` to my divs so that they would be side by side and it works well. I also succeeded in managing the height of the divs but I can't make the second div take all the remaining space.

I created a simplified jsfiddle for what I've done:

- I specified a size for the body to mimic the iframe behaviour.
- The image and the body size are just examples.

http://jsfiddle.net/e5whkna9/

As you can see on the fiddle:

- The black image (and the first div) takes the space it is supposed to.
- The yellow div (the second one) has a good height but it doesn't take all the remaining width.
- The pink div (the container) is not totally covered by my first and second divs.

From what I found, it is not really possible to take "all the remaining space" without an element with a defined width. I hope that I missed something because I don't know the width of the iframe before my javascript runs and I would like to avoid setting the dimensions of my divs with javascript.

## What I'm looking for

I'm looking for a solution or a pointer to a website that will help me understand and solve this problem: making the second div adapt to the remaining space.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If instead of using `inline-block` you would just float the first element, then the _contents_ of the second one would take up all the remaining space … http://jsfiddle.net/e5whkna9/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take out the display inline block from your side div.

```
  .side {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .first {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .second {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/e5whkna9/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I wanted to place some other divs with `position:absolute;` into the first and second divs. For that I need to give a `position:relative;` to my `.side` class. Is there a way to do it without having the second div covering the first div?