# Firefox behaviour: 2 divs side by side with variable width

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I'm trying to display 2 divs side by side in css.

- The first div has a variable width (in fonction of the image it contains).
- The second one has to take all the remaining width.
- The second div contains 3 sections: "top", "middle" and "bottom" whose added height is 100%.
- Both divs have a 100% height.

I successfully placed the divs side by side thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207925/positioning-2-div-side-by-side-in-a-squared-container-embed-in-an-iframe) and everything works great when the body has fixed dimensions.

But since I will embed this page in an iframe, I want the divs to occupy all the available space. I would like to avoid setting the body dimensions with javascript...

I decided to add this code to the body:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This does the trick on Chrome and Safari: the image has a 100% height which defines its width and the second div stretches until it occupies all the available space. (The caption is displayed over the image)

[image: Chrome/Safari screenshot (the black rectangle is my image)]

But when I use Firefox, the first pane is larger than expected (see the red rectangle).

[image: Firefox screenshot]

I created a fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/0w0s6z5n/1/

I can't understand why the behavior is different and what I did wrong on this page. Can someone explain to me why the behavior is different and point me in the right direction to succeed in displaying everything like it currently is on Chrome/Safari.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe you could try set a max-width property for the box? I can't test it out as don't have firefox, sorry, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Since I don't know the size of the body nor the size of the image in advance, I think I can't put an arbitrary `max-width` property. I would like the page to fully adapt to the available space.

Comment: True, Hopefully someone will know the solution, goodluck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
```

to `body` (*yeah, its that simple*)!! :)

Problem : container always takes dimension of parent elements, so you have to declare them if you intend to use them in `%`

css :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%; /* added */
    height: 100%; /* added */
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0w0s6z5n/5/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel dumb :) So Firefox needs me to define the dimensions of the body but the other browsers infer them?

Comment: @VincentDurmont : in general, this is rule of thumb...always declare the dimension and use `html,body` together, not just `body`.Older versions of IE also have this problem, so for cross browser uniformity, define it always!....Also, as a side note, always use `position` as a last resort! :)

Comment: Ok thank you. If I want to display a caption over my image, have I another way than using `position:absolute;`?

Comment: nope, for that, you'll have to make image `relative` and caption `absolute`, i just mentioned `position` as a last resort because you have made `body` as `absolute`...that is odd for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is exactly what you wanted, but from what i understood you need to have the first div with a variable width and the rest should fall in place.

I edited your code:  [**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f78rmgs7/)

CSS :

```
body {
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: orange;
}
.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: pink;
}
.first {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: red;
}
.second {
 height: 100%;
 background-color: yellow;
}
.media {
 height: 100%;
}
.caption {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 15%;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: grey;
}
.top {
 height: 40%;
 background-color: blue;
 }
.middle {
 height: 30%;
 background-color: purple;
 }
.bottom {
  height: 30%;
  background-color: green;
 }
```

With this if you change the width of .media , the rest of them fall in place and also works with firefox (Tested).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to have a width of 100% on the image. The dimensions can vary and I just want the image to have a 100% height. The width should adapt.

Comment: you can play around with the width as much as you want. You just have to set it to something and the rest will adapt. Go into the fiddle and change the .media width to whatever pixels you want. It will take the pixels and the rest will adapt to it.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear but the image is dynamically loaded and I don't know its dimensions. The only certainty I have is that the ratio height/width > 1.

Comment: oh ok ... then you set the parent div to width: 100 % , height: 100% ... in your case the body

Comment: That's what I did! Thank you very much for your time!